# gnuplot with .6 second

Tags: time, gnuplot

I have a dataset with timestamps and values. The timestamp has 6 digit milli seconds. I tried to use this `set format x "%H:%M:%.6S"` with gnuplot. However, gnuplot cannot recognize this and just groups the values together for each second in the plot:

```
set format x "%H:%M:%.6S"
```

The dataset looks like this:

```
16:28:11.690076 1

16:28:11.690198 12

16:28:11.710519 14

16:28:11.730769 53

16:28:11.770280 18

16:28:11.791748 12

16:28:11.893583 15
```

The first column is the timestamp and the second column is the value. I want to plot the time on the x axis and the value on the y axis.

Now, gnuplot only gives me a plot up to seconds, but not millisecond. Is there something I should have set?

Answer (score 1):

To read in time data you must use `set timefmt ...` to specify the format to use. Here, you must not specify the number of digits to use for the seconds, using `%S` reads the milliseconds as you specified them.

For the output you can set the number of digits:

```
set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'
set xdata time
set format x '%H:%M:%.3S'
plot 'test.txt' using 1:2 w lp pt 7 notitle
```

[image]